# Retrieving meta tags with R

Tags: r, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

This page, [How can I retrieve og/meta attributes of a resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312942/how-can-i-retrieve-og-meta-attributes-of-a-resource) , answers the question of how to retrieve the og/meta attributes generally.

Is there any way to do this type of retrieval using R?

Comment: I don't think there's a FB-specific package for R, but you should be able to parse that relatively easily using the **XML** package.

Comment: Cool, I'm a bit overloaded by the number of functions available. Could you point me to which function I might use?

Comment: Basically you need to use `xmlParse` or something similar to translate the text into an R data structure, then you'll use `xmlAttrs` to extract attributes. It can get kind of complicated quickly, though.