# Fetching metadata from url

Tags: java, html, ajax, cross-domain, metadata

I have used Jsoup library to fetch the metadata from url.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();  
String keywords = doc.select("meta[name=keywords]").first().attr("content");  
System.out.println("Meta keyword : " + keywords);  
String description = doc.select("meta[name=description]").get(0).attr("content");  
Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");  

String src = images.get(0).attr("src");
System.out.println("Meta description : " + description); 
System.out.println("Meta image URl : " + src);
```

But I want to do it in **client** side using javascript

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do it client only because of the [`cross-origin`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) issue. You need a server side script to get the content of the page.

<strike>**OR** You can use [`YQL`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). In this way, the `YQL` will used as proxy.</strike>
<sub>https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/product-atos/yql/index.htm</sub>

**Or** you can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com. In this way, cors-anywhere will used as proxy:

For example:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + $('input').val()
  }).then(function(data) {
    var html = $(data);

    $('#kw').html(getMetaContent(html, 'description') || 'no keywords found');
    $('#des').html(getMetaContent(html, 'keywords') || 'no description found');
    $('#img').html(html.find('img').attr('src') || 'no image found');
  });
});

function getMetaContent(html, name) {
  return html.filter(
  (index, tag) => tag && tag.name && tag.name == name).attr('content');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="Type URL here" value="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/" />
<button>Get Meta Data</button>

<pre>
  <div>Meta Keyword: <div id="kw"></div></div>
  <div>Description: <div id="des"></div></div>
  <div>image: <div id="img"></div></div>
</pre>
```

Comment: thanks for a solution but how I can show the image from the URL.
P.S the URL contain many images how to show the best one from it.

Comment: `the best one from it` How do you know who the best?

Comment: is this is a stable solution to be used in a social network to scrape meta data from urls, like facebook do it? can it handle many concurrent requests?

Comment: @Engineeroholic I was not tested it with many requests. I'm sure Facebook doesn't do this. The "right" solution is to use a "proxy" server. For more info. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/863110) answer.

Comment: This works here, but I get a 403 host error when i add it to my site. Any suggestions? I copied it word for word

Comment: What's the url you're trying to fetch?

Comment: cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/q1HQHpIgMxHSlnWnkwx5LrYH5WyZJmmUGNQM1tycfmR0qf0mFuChzU5STJY3FT1H:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Invalid host)

Comment: Nvm - I got it ... the input field was messed up, when manually entering everything worked ! Thanks so much for the post!

Answer (score 0):

## Pure Javascript function

From node.js backend (Next.js) I use that:

```
export const fetchMetadata = async (url) => {
    const html = await (await fetch(url, {
        timeout: 5000,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    })).text()
    
    var metadata = {};
    html.replace(/<meta.+(property|name)="(.*?)".+content="(.*?)".*\/>/igm, (m,p0, p1, p2)=>{ metadata[p1] = decode(p2) } );
    return metadata
}

export const decode = (str) => str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {
    return String.fromCharCode(dec);
})
```

You could use it on the client with https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`open-graph-scraper`](https://github.com/jshemas/openGraphScraper) for this, [for more info see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73748415/827129).