# fetch data from url like facebook using angular2

Tags: angular

I have try so many thing to featch the data from url like facebook, i have search through the google but still not getting any code that can provide the tittle, description & image from url as just like Facebook,
I know by the use of Meta Tags i can able to featch the data from the url,
I angular documentation there are some method in but in documentation they have not clear all the method how they can be used for featch data from url
this is the documentation link: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta ,

& i have also try some code which is present on google these link are given below:
https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ng2-meta

can any body help me out in this senario, how do i do it?

i want do it using angular2 or angular4

Comment: what is it you are actually trying to do? Fetch the OpenGraph meta data from a remote page ?

Comment: i just want to featch the Tittle, Description, & the  image from the the URL & the URL will be provider by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you have tried only relate to the web content you are delivering from your app, not data from an external Url.

The info you need can be extracted from the remote page by loading it's html and parsing the data.

An example of how this might be done is here

[Fetching metadata from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911262/fetching-metadata-from-url)

Comment: url which you have send it to me , it is clearly written that:     " You can't do it client only because of the cross-origin issue. You need a server side script to get the content of the page."  but i need to know that is there any way to do that   at the client side only.