# Fetch Meta data of any website using only frontend for Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

As seen on [this tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) under the heading **"Cross-Domain from Chrome Extensions"**, it states that

> Chrome extensions can make cross-domain requests to any domain *if* the domain is included in the "permissions" section of the manifest.json

So I have included `"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` in my `manifest.json` but it still doesn't work

I am using https://github.com/jacktuck/unfurl but it throws a weird error

> Failed to load https://akshaykadam.me/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. e TypeError: Failed to fetch

My basic code is like this -

```
import unfurl from "unfurl";

_fetchMeta = async () => {
    try {
        let result = await unfurl({
            uri: "https://akshaykadam.me",
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }
        });
        console.log("result", result);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("e", e);
    }
};
```

The full code can be found at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/unfurl-chrome-extension-bug

I need to fetch Open Graph Tags or Meta Tags of any website using only frontend. And with the above code it doesn't work as a Chrome extension or as a React Frontend Website

Do I need to use it like a proxy as shown in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774307/6141587 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911711/6141587?

Or can I do it from purely frontend without any proxy or a server?

Or do I have to use `unfurl` on the server & I can send my requests through it?

## Edit:

This works with `axios` as shown [here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/unfurl-chrome-extension-bug/blob/master/src/App.js#L13) so its probably an `unfurl` issue. I'll update this post once I get reply on https://github.com/jacktuck/unfurl/issues/38

Comment: @wOxxOm 1) it also doesn't work without `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` I tried it already. I'll try removing the Service Worker. Its created by default with `create-react-app` 2) I click on the PopUp & it opens the React App but when I right-click & open Inspect & check the console, it throws the big error in yellow color above "Failed to load" (the 2nd yellow color one)

Comment: @wOxxOm I meant that only just communicated wrongly. ""I click on the PopUp & it opens the React App" - what do you mean?" I mean that when I click the Icon, it opens up the PopUp which throws the error when you right click & click on Inspect on the PopUp

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

The issue was that https://github.com/jacktuck/unfurl is using `node-fetch` so it can't work in browser as stated in `node-fetch`s [LIMITS section](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/master/LIMITS.md)

> Topics such as Cross-Origin, Content Security Policy, Mixed Content, Service Workers are ignored, given our server-side context

If it changes to https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch then it will work with any environment & I can just use `unfurl` to get meta tags from any URL as Chrome extensions don't have to worry about Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS issue) as long as you mention `"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` in `manifest.json`

Keep an eye  on this issue https://github.com/jacktuck/unfurl/issues/38

As soon as it closes `unfurl` will work in any environment :)