# Fetching metadata from url -axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have used the Axios library to fetch the metadata from the URL.

```
export default class HsLinkLoder {

    private static _instance: HsLinkLoder;

    private constructor() {
    }

    public static getInstance(): HsLinkLoder {
        // Do you need arguments? Make it a regular static method instead.
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new HsLinkLoder());
    }


    public async lodeLink(url:string){
        await axios.get(url,{

        }).then(r=>{
            this.getMetaContent(r.data,"description")
            console.log(r.data.filter('meta'))
            console.log(JSON.stringify(r.data))
        }).catch(e=>{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
        })
    }



    public getMetaContent(html:Document , name:string) {
       console.log(html.getElementsByTagName(name));
    }

}
```

I tried to read Meta using this function posted on this question

[Fetching metadata from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911262/fetching-metadata-from-url)

```
public getMetaContent(html:any, name:string) {
        return html.filter((index:any, tag:any) => tag && tag.name && tag.name == name).attr('content');
    }
```

But it's not working. I am getting an empty response.

How to use this function with the Axios?

Comment: Please create [`MVCE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I updated my question with my full code class

Comment: what will be the value of `link`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee the link will be the URL

Comment: Update that in the question