# Open Graph meta tags do not work as expected

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Our website contains single image pages. To achieve beautiful image views on social networks, I have setup almost all the neccessary OpenGraph's (`og:`) meta tags. Here they are:

```
<title>Some title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Some description">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="CompanyName">            
<meta property="og:title" content="Photo by @someuser">                
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.companydomain.com/209114427002202.jpg">    
<meta name="medium" content="image">                    
<meta property="og:type" content="mycompanynamespace:photo">
<meta property="og:description" content="Some slogan">            
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="108569252539534">                
<meta property="og:url" content="https://companydomain.com/image/2030203020320302">
```

However it doesn't work as expected. What it shows is just a domain's name:

[image]

What I want is to set it to be like Instagram. What's the magic behind the Instagram 'configuration'? And how to set a logo for the right bottom corner?

[image]

Comment: _“What's the magic behind the Instagram 'configuration'?”_ – most of the time that magic is called, “being owned by Facebook, and therefor able to do stuff other, 3rd-party apps can’t.”

Answer (score 1):

Engineer, you have 2 situations here:

1. Handling Open Graph Meta Tags:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313817/854222
2. Bootstrap Hover Image:
   https://miketricking.github.io/dist/

You need to be able to handle the meta tags in order to display them using a CSS overlay, like the option #2.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you misunderstood my question. I do not want to implement my own sharing views (e.g. like people do in chats, forums, comments, etc...) based on og tags. I just want to configure my page's og tags so, that it's been shown in social networks not so poor(see my picture in question,it's just domain and some arrow), but like Instagram (see in attached picture in above)

Comment: Engineer, in order to add more information on the footer of the image, besides the domain and arrow that is right now, you can work adding different elements as it' shown for example, in the hover example #10 in: https://miketricking.github.io/dist/

Comment: Thanks. Again, you misunderstood my question. I just want to "convince" facebook or other social networks to render my shared website pages with my chosen icons and text.

Comment: You need to customize your values with CSS and jQuery, according to your requirement, and override the original style You have the tools to do it. Good luck...